# How many Tarantino films are set in the same universe?

Tags: quentin-tarantino

Django Unchained and Inglorius Basterds are both set in the same alternative history universe according to [Tarantino](http://www.nme.com/filmandtv/news/quentin-tarantino-plans-inglorious-basterds-django/295888). How many of the films made by Tarantino are set in the same universe? Are any of the films he's wrote or starred in but not directed set in the same universe?

Comment: At first the question itself didn't make much sense to me but, reading TylerShads answer I realise this is a crafty, intelligent question! Made my day!

Comment: Red Apple cigarettes in Pulp Fiction and Kill Bill vol.1

Comment: Red apple tobacco is mentioned in the hateful eight, too.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Tarantino is an odd figure, creating actual Universes for each of his characters that all tie into one another somehow.

They are broken up in a few categories including the **Realer than Real Universe** which include his *history-altering* pieces like *Basterds* where these people are supposed to be living in a real world, as in the way Hitler was offed in this Universe, as far as the people in *Pulp Fiction* are concerned, actually happened.

The first evidence of this was brought on with a connection between *Pulp Fiction* and *Reservoir Dogs* where we have the **Vega** brothers, Vic and Vincent.  Also, as a subtle hint, [this image](http://25.media.tumblr.com/e5f26345f628a1742b15d0faff2d95a6/tumblr_mh9lfku35S1qgg5pwo1_500.png) shows the connection between Pulp Fiction and Django Unchained with Captain Koons.

Then, we have what he refers to as the **Movie Movie Universe** where these movies are movies that the characters in his *Realer than Real Universe* can go see at their local theatre.

An interesting theory that has come of this is that Mia Wallace from Pulp Fiction could actually be playing The Bride - Beatrix Kiddo in Kill Bill, as she did attempt an acting career before and the *Fox Force Five* failed pilot has a lot of similarities to *Kill Bill*

In a matter to complicate things, it has been stated that he has characters than can *crossover* these borders to be in both universes; supposedly Winston Wolf as well as a lowly guard Earl McGraw meet this criteria.

Finally, we have *Jackie Brown* which apparently doesn't meet any of these criteria and is in it's own universe called the **Elmore Leonard Universe**.  It seems this is set in its own universe because it was an adaptation of someone else's work, therefore it is set in its own universe entirely for this reason.

Explained rather briefly but still effectively in this little [wiki page](http://wiki.tarantino.info/index.php/Universes) it states simply that

- Reservoir Dogs
- True Romance
- Pulp Fiction
- Death Proof
- Inglorious Basterds
- Django Unchained

  Are all a part of the **Realer than Real Universe**

While

- Natural Born Killers
- From Dusk 'Till Dawn
- Kill Bill 1&2

Are all a part of the **Movie Movie Universe**

This image, shows a great visual connection of all these movies...though it is a bit outdated.

[image]

Comment: So, nested universes.  Cool.

Comment: Wow apparently there is more to it than I thought. This is a great break down but I'm still curious about a few shorts and tv shows that he's directed as well as anything that he's acted in as to whether or not they are then connected to his Universes. Also do you know if these are his terms for them? It sounds like him. Also this really helps to explain why Jackie Brown is so different than his other films.

Comment: The terms are his, and as far as I'm aware this has only to do with his major films, mostly pictures above in the end graphic.  I can do a bit of digging for his smaller stuff but I doubt it.

Comment: +1 Wow, what the? Never had expected *Tarantino* to put that much thought in it and it sounded like mere *"fan fiction"* at first. But then again, it's *Tarantino*.

Comment: [This reddit post](http://www.reddit.com/r/AskReddit/comments/ubaqq/what_fan_theories_have_blown_your_mind_with_their/c4tzvnn) helps demonstrate the effects that Basterds has on the Pulp Fiction/Reservoir Dogs timelines.

Comment: My goodness! Who woulda thought theres so much going on behind the screens too. Thx TylerShads for connecting the dots and enlightening me.

Comment: @KeyBrdBasher I didn't do most of this, just regurgitating what I've read :)  Credit goes to the people smarter than I that saw the connections.

Comment: Kudos to those unknown faces too!

Answer (score 9):

### Tarantino Universe:

**Chronological order of the films:**

1. Django Unchained
2. The Hateful Eight
3. From Dusk Till Dawn 3: The Hangman's Daughter
4. Inglourious Basterds
5. Reservoir Dogs
6. True Romance
7. Natural Born Killers
8. Four Rooms
9. Jackie Brown
10. Death Proof
11. Planet Terror
12. From Dusk Till Dawn
13. From Dusk Till Dawn 2: Texas Blood Money
14. Curdled
15. Pulp Fiction
16. Kill Bill Volume 1
17. Kill Bill Volume 2

**Interconnections:**

- Dr. King Schultz and Paula Schultz - King Dr. Schulz is a character
  in the movie "Django Unchained," German dentist turned bounty hunter.
  Paula Schultz is the name of that grave Beatrix Kiddo character of
  the Bride films "Kill Bill Volume 1 and Kill Bill Volume 2" was
  buried. Paula Schultz was the wife of Dr. King Schultz.
- Gerald Nash, Marvin Nash and Gerald Nash - Gerald Nash is a member of
  Gang Bacall. Django Freeman and Dr. King Schultz are searching for
  their leader, Smitty Bacall, in the movie "Django Unchained." Marvin
  Nash is the tortured cop in "Reservoir Dogs." Gerald Nash is a
  policeman killed by the Knox couple, his death is mentioned in the TV
  program in "Natural Born Killers". Gerald Nash is the
  great-grandfather of Gerald and Marvin. Marvin and Gerald are
  cousins.
- Crazy Craig Koons and Captain Koons - Crazy Craig Koons is a member
  of Gang Bacall. Django Freeman and Dr. King Schultz are searching for
  their leader, Smitty Bacall, in the movie "Django Unchained." Captain
  Koons is a character in "Pulp Fiction", played by Christopher Walken.
  Crazy Craig Koons is the great-grandfather of Captain Koons.
- Red Apple Cigarettes - the cigarette brand created by Tarantino can
  be seen in the films "Django Unchained," "Inglourious Basterds,"
  "Reservoir Dogs," "Four Rooms," "Death Proof," "Planet Terror," "From
  Dusk Till Dawn," "Pulp Fiction," "Kill Bill Volume 1 "and" Kill Bill
  Volume 2."
- Santanico Pandemonium - is a character in the movie "From Dusk Till
  Dawn 3: The Hangman's Daughter" and "From Dusk Till Dawn." Santanico
  is a stripper in the club Titty Twister in Mexico, she is also a
  vampire queen. In "From Dusk Till Dawn 3: The Hangman's Daughter" is
  revealed that her real name was Esmeralda.
- Titty Twister - is a vampire bar that appears in the movies "From
  Dusk Till Dawn 3: The Hangman's Daughter" and "From Dusk Till Dawn”. 
  The curious fact is that in the movie "From Dusk Till Dawn" it is completely destroyed, but in the movie "From Dusk Till Dawn 2: Texas 
  Blood Money" there's another vampire bar with the same name.
- Razor Charlie and Razor Eddie – are the brothers working as bartender
  in Titty Twister, and are also vampires. Razor Charlie appears in the
  movies "From Dusk Till Dawn 3: The Hangman's Daughter" and "From Dusk
  Till Dawn." Razor Eddie in the movie "From Dusk Till Dawn 2: Texas
  Blood Money."
- Sergeant Donny Donowitz and filmmaker Lee Donowitz - Sergeant Donny
  Donowitz is a character in the movie "Inglourious Basterds", member
  of the Bastards, known as The Bear Jew. The filmmaker Lee Donowitz is
  a very successful film producer in Hollywood, character in the movie
  "True Romance". Lee is the son of Sergeant Donny Donowitz.
- Vic Vega and Vincent Vega - Vic Vega, aka Vic Palito or Mr. Blonde is
  a bank robber character with psychopath mentality in the movie
  "Reservoir Dogs." Vincent Vega is a gangster in the movie "Pulp
  Fiction." Vic and Vincent are brothers.
- Larry Dimmick, Alabama Whitma and Jimmie Dimmick - Larry is known as 
  Mr. White, a bank robber, a character from the movie "Reservoir
  Dogs." Jimmie Dimmick is a character from "Pulp Fiction", played by
  Quentin Tarantino. Alabama Whitman is the main character in the movie
  "True Romance". Larry Dimmick has already done some criminal work in 
  partnership with Alabama Whitman. Larry Dimmick is also the uncle of 
  Jimmie Dimmick.
- The briefcase with diamonds in the movie "Reservoir Dogs" is the same
  mysterious briefcase in "Pulp Fiction."
- Big Kahuna Burger - Fictitious Hawaiian restaurant. It appears or is
  mentioned in the following films "Reservoir Dogs," "Four Rooms,"
  "Death Proof," "From Dusk Till Dawn" and "Pulp Fiction."
- Gas Can – Petrol gallon in the Tarantino universe. It shows up in
  "Reservoir Dogs," "Pulp Fiction" and "Kill Bill Volume 2."
- Seymour Scagnetti and Jack Scagnetti - Seymour Scagnetti is the
  officer mentioned in the movie "Reservoir Dogs" by Mr. Blonde.
  Detective Jack Scagnetti chases the Knox couple in the movie "Natural
  Born Killers". Seymour and Jack are brothers.
- Jack Rabbit Slim's – Fifties style restaurant mentioned on the radio
  during the death of Mr. Blonde in "Reservoir Dogs". In fact, it is
  the only restaurant in the movie "Pulp Fiction."
- Fruit Brute Cereal is a cereal brand that was actually on the market
  in the 70s. Another characteristic of Tarantino's movies, it appears
  in the movies "Reservoir Dogs" and "Pulp Fiction."
- Long Hair Yuppie Scum-, discrete character who appears in the film
  "Four Rooms" vomiting and running during the restaurant robbery of
  the film "Pulp Fiction."
- Teriyaki Donut, Japanese restaurant in the films of Quentin
  Tarantino, presented in "Jackie Brown" and "Pulp Fiction."
- Acuna Boys Tex-Mex Food - food brand in Tarantino universe with
  references in films the "Jackie Brown" and "Death Proof."
- Butch Coolidge and Livingston Beaumont - Beaumont Livingston is a
  character played by Chris Tucker in the movie "Jackie Brown." Butch
  is played by Bruce Willis in the movie "Pulp Fiction". Both
  characters live in the same neighborhood.
- Jungle Julia is a popular radio DJ in Austin, Texas with a broad
  knowledge of music. Character in the movie "Death Proof", his death
  is mentioned on the radio in the movie "Planet Terror".
- The crazy babysitter twins are characters who have a cameo
  participation in the movie "Death Proof" and become more important in
  the movie "Planet Terror."
- Sheriff Earl McGraw, Sheriff Edgar McGraw and Dr. Dakota Block -
  Sheriff Earl McGraw is a character from the movie "Death Proof",
  "Planet Terror", "From Dusk Till Dawn" and "Kill Bill Volume 2."
  Sheriff Edgar McGraw is a character of the film "Death Proof," "From
  Dusk Till Dawn 2: Texas Blood Money" and "Kill Bill Volume 2". Dr.
  Dakota Block is a character in the movies "Death Proof" and "Planet
  Terror". Sheriff Earl McGraw is the father of Sheriff Edgar McGraw
  and Dr. Dakota Block.
- G.O. Juice is a juice brand that appears in the movie "Death Proof"
  and "Kill Bill Volume 1."
- Jasper is a character that wants to sell a car in the movie "Death
  Proof" and tries to abuse the bride character in the movie "Kill Bill
  Volume 1" and "Kill Bill Volume 2."
- Gecko Brothers are the main characters in the movie "From Dusk Till
  Dawn" and also appear on the TV show Miami DOA news in the movie
  "Curdled".
- A reporter in the movies "From Dusk Till Dawn" and "Curdled”
  reporting the crimes that are occurring.
- Gabriela / Esmeralda Villalobos is the same character that only
  changes her name. In the movie "Curdled" she is called Gabriela and
  in the movie "Pulp Fiction" her name is Esmeralda Villalobos.
- The samurai sword - Butch Coolidge, character in the movie "Pulp
  Fiction", and the bride character in the films "Kill Bill Volume 1"
  and "Kill Bill Volume 2" use swords made by Hattori Hanzo character
  in the movie "Kill Bill Volume 1 ".