# Does "The Hateful Eight" belong to the Tarantino Universe?

Tags: quentin-tarantino, the-hateful-eight

It is well known that the majority of Tarantino movies are set in the same fictional Universe. I just wonder what are, if any, the cross-references that make "The Hateful Eight" part of the same puzzle.

In one of the answers to this question - ["How many Tarantino films are set in the same universe?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/10004/how-many-tarantino-films-are-set-in-the-same-universe)" - it is mentioned that "The Hateful Eight" is indeed the part of that universe. But I guess it would be nice to have some clarification on this issue.

Comment: I think yes, he gave some hint in some interview i think.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Tim Roth's character in The Hateful Eight is apparently an ancestor of one of the Inglourious Basterds.

From the ew.com article, [How Quentin Tarantino's Hateful Eight links to Inglourious Basterds](http://www.ew.com/article/2015/12/15/quentin-tarantino-hateful-eight-inglourious-basterds-connection-spinoff):

> Tim Roth (*Reservoir Dogs*, *Pulp Fiction*) plays Oswaldo “The Little Man” Mobray in the post-Civil War western, and the actor recently told the Huffington Post that the character is linked to someone from another Tarantino film.
>
> “I won’t say which one,” Roth said. “He’s the great-great-grandfather of one of the characters in *Inglourious Basterds*.”

Answer (score 11):

Yes, all the films, including *The Hateful Eight*, are a part of the same cinematic universe.

In an [interview released just seventeen hours ago](http://www.dazeddigital.com/artsandculture/article/29265/1/quentin-tarantino-confirms-that-all-his-films-are-connected), Tarantino clarified that the films *Kill Bill* and *From Dusk Til Dawn* are the film within the films from the "Real Universe" that the characters watch. The "Real Universe" is the cinematic world where everything takes place in the same setting.

According to Tarantino, in the [article published by *Dazed Digital*](http://www.dazeddigital.com/artsandculture/article/29265/1/quentin-tarantino-confirms-that-all-his-films-are-connected):

> There is actually two separate universes. There is the realer than
>   real universe, alright, and all the characters inhabit that one. But
>   then there's this movie universe. So *From Dusk Till Dawn*, *Kill Bill*,
>   they all take place in this special movie universe. So when all the
>   characters of *Reservoir Dogs* or *Pulp Fiction*, when they go to the
>   movies, *Kill Bill* is what they go to see. *From Dusk Till Dawn* is what
>   they see.

In an updated version of that same article, Tarantino [confirmed](http://www.dazeddigital.com/artsandculture/article/29274/1/playing-detective-in-tarantino-s-movie-universes) that at least one of the characters in *The Hateful Eight* is in fact related to a character from a previous film, which takes place further along the timeline.

> I don’t want to say it point blank ‘boom’, but if you’re a fan of my
>   work and are familiar with it you could be a bit of a detective. I
>   will say that there is one character amongst the eight that is related
>   to one of my other characters in one of my other films.

As for the identity, Tarantino has not affirmatively confirmed, but the strongest clues hint at Tim Roth's Oswaldo Mobray, aka **Pete Hicox**, who shares the same legal name with Michael Fassbender's **Archie Hicox** in *Inglourious Basterds*.

Comment: And how does *The Hateful Eight* then figure into this, which is the actual question asked here?

Comment: How am I supposed to add additional references? Did I not include a link to an article in which Tarantino answers the question?

Comment: You only said some general things about the relation between some of the films. There's no information at all about *The Hateful Eight* here.

Comment: You could add the quote about the hateful eight character having a secret relative in the real universe, from that same article.

Answer (score 8):

At some point, Bob smokes a Manzana Roja (*Red Apple* in Spanish) cigarette, and Minnie has a cigarette with Red Apple tobacco. This Fictional brand has appeared before in other Tarantino films, although I think this is the first time it's suggested to have a foothold in the Spanish-speaking market.

Comment: Are these fictional brands that are exclusive to Tarantino films?

Comment: @Richard Yes. (Cite: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quentin_Tarantino)

Comment: @makihige You might want to add this information into the actual answer.

Answer (score 7):

To add to Carl Fink's answer (don't have enough reputation to comment), Tim Roth's character's real name is "English" Pete Hicox, while Michael Fassbender's very British character in Inglourious Basterds is Archie Hicox. That's almost certainly the connection, or at least one of them.

Answer (score 4):

Yes,it is indeed a part of the "Tarantino Cinematic Universe", as is evident from the following points:

1. Mexican Bob smokes a Manzana Roja cigarette which translates to Red Apple cigarette, the infamous Tarantino cigarettes .
2. Miny smokes Red Apple tobacco, another Red Apple reference.
3. Oswaldo Mobray whose real name is English Pete Hicox, is the grandfather of Lt. Archie Hicox from *Inglourious Basterds*.